# How to activate apache2 service on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, flask, web, server, raspberry-pi

After trying to run "service apache2 reload" on the raspberry terminal, I get an error

The error log reads:
"apache2.service is not active, cannot reload."

How do I activate "apache2.service" on the raspberry pi?

I've already installed apache2 on my raspberry pi, but I can't reload it.

Comment: Can you add the error log?

Comment: I tried to run __sudo service apache2 start__ and I get another error:  "Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details."    How do I fix that error

Comment: post the output of this command `systemctl status apache2.service` and also this `journalctl -xe`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one `sudo service apache2 start` . Make sure apache is properly installed in your system.